# Как правильно распарсить строку по словам и сохранить разделители

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Есть, к примеру, такая строка `qweSSXFF rrrrrFfF7f syyyyyearssssssyear`
Подскажите как распарсить её по разделителям-словам и сохранить и разделители, и то, что между ними? а то какая-то ерунда выходит. Пример на java. Разделители в regex. Смысл в том, чтобы искать в строке именно те слова, которые есть в regex, т.е например: строка->разделитель(искомое слово) - wFFE4->FF, qw Ff9zx1->FF9, 239FF->9FF. или такой пример с регулярным `String regex = "(?i)RR|SYYYY|SSSSS|ff\\d|ff(?=\\D)|SSXFF|E|YEAR|SYEAR";` - HH:MI:SSXFF ищем SSXFF, но данное регулярное выражение не найдёт SSXFF.
(буква\цифра\символ, которые могут быть или нет)(искомое слово)(буква\цифра\символ, которые могут быть или нет)

```
String s = "qweSSXFF rrrrrFfF7f syyyyyearssssssyear";
String regex = "(?i)(?<=RR|SYYYY|SSSSS|ff\\d|ff(?=\\D)|SSXFF|E|YEAR|SYEAR)" +
    "|(?=RR|SYYYY|SSSSS|[^x]ff\\d|ff|SSXFF|E|YEAR|SYEAR)";
String[] ftmSplit = s.split(regex);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Напишите в вопросе ожидаемый результат

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать следующий код:

```
public static String[] splitIncludingDelimiters(String regex, String text) {
    List<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(text);

    StringBuffer sbuf = new StringBuffer();
    while(matcher.find()){
        matcher.appendReplacement(sbuf, matcher.group()); 
        list.add(sbuf.toString());
        sbuf.setLength(0);  // очистка буфера
    }

    matcher.appendTail(sbuf); // добавление оставшейся части строки
    if (sbuf.length() > 0) list.add(sbuf.toString());

    return list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
}
```

[Пример использования метода](https://ideone.com/2LwQvu):

```
String s = "qweSSXFF rrrrrFfF7f syyyyyearssssssyear";
String regex = "(?i)RR|SYYYY|SSSSS|ff\\d|ff(?=\\D)|SSXFF|E|YEAR|SYEAR";
String[] res = splitIncludingDelimiters(regex, s);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(res));
// => [qwe, SSXFF,  rr, rr, rFf, F7f syyyy, year, sssss, syear]
```

Comment: rFf - не подходит, т.к должен найти только Ff. Так же если строка будет HH:MI:SSXFF, то SSXFF не будет найден. Суть загвоздки в том, что не могу точно вытянуть слова со строки. Например: wFFE4->FF, qw Ff9zx1->FF9, 239FF->9FF - как задать подобные правила для поиска совпадений?

Comment: @user_Kyrt Добавьте эти требования в вопрос.

Comment: добавил требования

Comment: @user_Kyrt Вы сами пробовали читать вопрос? Я понимаю только то, что есть строка `qweSSXFF rrrrrFfF7f syyyyyearssssssyear`, что вопрос звучит как "распарсить её по разделителям-словам и сохранить и разделители, и то, что между ними" - то есть мой ответ как раз на это и отвечает, но что вам надо из неё получить - вообще неясно. У вас есть строки-разделители в виде `List<String>` / `String[]`? Вы пытаетесь что-то извлечь или всё-таки разбить на совпадения-несовпадения?